# Should I use the app.config or custom xml file for data init in my project when I have N items to init?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-services

I'm writing a multi threaded win service that on load should read a list of N queue names and than init a queue reader class for each queue name.

What would be the right way to go ? to hold a list.xml file with all the queue names (and 3-4 more values per queue name) or put custom data in the app.config for this (which will require me to implement ConfigurationElementCollection / ConfigurationElement  in my application (longer way to go).

Thx.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the config - it's exactly for this purpose.
I have seen configs that are hundreds of lines long.

Comment: Although It means I need to work "harder" to implement the ability to read custom configurations... ?

Answer (score 1):

If the list is to change during run time, I would use separate xml file otherwise app.config. this way I could drop a new file every time I need to without worrying about messing up app.config.

In your case you say it is done only during startup, then app.config is better.

But all depends on personal choice and how it fits into the whole architecture.

Comment: also consider that the config info goes in different places inside the registry on 32 vs 64 bit systems.  And if it ever runs on unix then another difference.  if any of this matters, then roll your own with xml.

Comment: But op never mentioned registry. Or did I miss that? App.config always go in the same folder as the executable. And also if the question was tagged c#, winforms and winservice, Unix seems out of scope.

Comment: No registry... Just need on startup to read list of Queue names and 3-4 params for each queue and thats all.